# Wygwam CKeditor images not working in Multi-Site

Tags: wygwam, multi-site-manager, image, uploads

I have Wygwam 2.7.1 / EE 2.5.5 - When trying to add an image in the CkEditor - the 'Browse Server' button has disappeared on all multi-sites but is present and working in the main site.

I am using the CP inside the main site and switching between sites, but as above, can't browse server or upload through the file manager on any multi-sites.

File Browser is working fine across sites.

Any similar experiences? Fixes?

Comment: I'm having the same problem right now. EE 2.8.0 and Wygwam 3.2.2. Did you found out how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The `Browse Server` button only appears when the upload directory belongs to the current site.

In the Wygwam settings you can create different configurations. By default there are the `Basic` and `Full` configuration.

You can use the clone function to duplicate the configuration you're using now. For me this is `Basic`. After you clone it you can rename it to `Basic {site_name}` and change the `Upload Directory to a directory that belongs to the matching site.

Now you can go to the channel field and change `Editor Configuration` to your newly made configuration.